# RAM for Laptop, Configuration

Tags: laptop, memory

i've a Dell 1545 and i need to put additional RAM. The laptop normally uses  DDR2-667, PC2-5300 200pin. Can i use a RAM 2GB PC2-6400 DDR2 800 SODIMM  in it?

Answer (score 0):

It should work. PC2-6400 SODIMMs up to 4GB are listed as supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as long as:

- It is the same type (DDR2)
- same format (SoDIMM)
- uses the same voltage (almost always the case for DDR2-SoDIMMS)
- and your computer support SoDIMMs of that size (David already checked that).
- And it is fast enough.

Consider the following car analogy for the last point:
You need a car which can do at least 66.7 kmph.   (DDR2-667)
You can also use a car which can do up to 80.0 kmph and drive it slower.  (DDR2-800)